Lag before writing the last output of HLS segment file
The Problem:
I use ffmpeg to cut video online from SRT server (https://github.com/Haivision/srt) to HLS and send the segment data to remote server.
This sends .m3u8 and .ts files at a certain interval during the stream.
But ffmpeg put the last segments only AFTER the client disconnected with SRT. That's why there is a delay when watching the stream.
The delay is the same as idle_streams_timeout (https://github.com/Edward-Wu/srt-live-server/wiki/Directives#idle_streams_timeout).
What I've tried:
Add FFMPEG parameters:

-i
flush_packets 1 (+ saving segment files to my local machine)
hls_flags delete_segments
fflags nobuffer
flags low_delay

What I'm doing that produces this issue:
Run the following commands:

ffmpeg -report -loglevel debug -i srt://{srt_url} -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -acodec aac -f hls -hls_time 4 -fflags flush_packets -method PUT {uploader_url}

or

ffmpeg -report -loglevel debug -i srt://{srt_url} -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -acodec aac -f hls -hls_time 4 -fflags flush_packets /path/to/segments/output.m3u8

In logs ffmpeg is oppening the latest segment file (stream2.ts) only after "All streams finished":
...
[out/hls] All streams finished
[out/hls] Terminating thread with return code 0 (success)
[hls] Opening 'http://127.0.0.1/api/streams/stream2.ts' for writing

